# Android Studio 3.0: Unable to delete file

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.0

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Sometimes when I try to start app I get the next error:

```
Error:java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: myproject\common\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar
> Unable to delete file: myproejct\common\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar
```

The proccess **java.exe** lock this. Why?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to the source file directly. Close the studio or the project and go to the path the issue is located at and delete the folder there.

If this doesn't work try
Go to the File> Settings> Build,Execution,Deployment> Instant Run > Uncheck this Check box (Enable Instant Run)

And then  `gradlew clean` in the console

Comment: I build project by gradle from console: 'gradlew assembleDebug' , and after that I get error that can't delete file. But if I build proejct by gradlew from Android Studio the problem is gone.

Comment: @user8945148 That means you did not run the command as root/ Administrator

Comment: Hmmm, I'm admin on my machine

Comment: @Alex You need to use root in the console/Terminal/ command prompt

Comment: @Alex which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 (64 bits)

Comment: @Alex so if you were using command prompt, first run it as Administrator

Comment: For what it's worth, closing AS and deleting the file manually worked for me. Once that was done I Rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 4):

Try running android studio as Administrator, right click on the Android studio shortcut then "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the Instant Run

Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

Comment: I wan't to turn off Instant Run because Google team advise to turn ON Instant Run.